# jQuery search for class

Tags: jquery, search, class

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class3">text</li>
    <li class="class4">text</li>
    <li class="class5">text</li>
</ul>
```

**How do I search for some class inside `.list`?**

Like:

```
search for .class1 inside .list () {
     // do something if true
} else {
     // do something if false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery just uses CSS selectors.  So use the descendant selector.

```
var $items = $('.list > .class1');

if ( $items.length ) {
  // do something here
} else {
  // if false
}
```

Comment: @Happy I'm not sure what you're asking there.

Answer (score 2):

```
var classOneEl = $('.list').find('.class1');
```

Or any of the other answers will work. Many ways.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over every element in ul.list:

```
$('.list').each(function() {
  //do something here
});
```

To access a more specific element you can use a more specific CSS selector:

```
$('.list > .class1').each(function() {
   //do something here
}
```

You can also assign it to a variable.  The operations you perform on it may will logically depend on how many elements the selector contains.

```
//example
var listItem1 = $('.list > .class1');
listItem1.hide();
```

Comment: $('.list').each(... iterates over each .list element, not every element in ul.list.  You're looking for $('.list > *') or $('.list').children()

Comment: You are correct, I missed that. I'd update it to $('ul.list > li').each(/*...*/);